# Idea: Moneropedia Mondays

Tags: discussion

[Moneropedia](https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/moneropedia/) is sorely lacking. I propose that each Monday, we ask questions about topics on Moneropedia, and [then add the answers to it](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/how-can-i-edit-a-moneropedia-definition-or-add-a-new-one)!

We could set topics to provide more focus and create really fleshed out entries, but I think keeping it generic would also work pretty well.

Comment: @2quick4u it seems like there is some support. Should we make it official?

Comment: sorry I did not notice your comment earlier. I am open to starting next week unless someone objects to a scheduling conflict with MAAM on Reddit.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5aep15/moneropedia_monday_1/

Answer (score 5):

I like that proposal and see benefits for both resources.

But, keep in mind that questions and answers on Stack Exchange are licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). I see the getmonero site [publishes the *majority* of the content](https://getmonero.org/legal/copyright) under the terms of cc by 3.0.

If you find a proper way to mark the contents of the Moneropedia cc by-sa and always keep a proper attribution underneath copied content, I don't see any issues here. Though, I'd prefer a technical solution. Maintaining attributions manually could quickly become a mess.

What about just automatically importing the feed of [top questions](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) and reference them in Moneropedia instead of maintaining the wiki separately?

Comment: We could ask for the answerer's permission to include it in Moneropedia. The technical solution to attribution is to [link each page to its GitHub entry](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/pull/159), and make sure each commit attributes back to the original author of the content.

Answer (score 3):

I really like this idea, especially the focus part, though we should probably not be too strict about it. That said, I would definitely participate in MoneropediaMonday